# Get value of table cell on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of a table cell by click a button in the same row of this cell. this cell is in the previous column of the button's column, this is my trying code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                        </th>
                        
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                        </th>
                        
                        
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                            </td>
                           
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group-sm">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addArticle(this)">Add</button>
                                    
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JS:

```
function addArticle(btn) {

    var RowNumber = btn.previousSibling.innerHTML;
    alert(RowNumber);
}
```

This code is not working,it displays undefined. Any help?

Comment: We need to see all of the relevant HTML in order to help you. I would guess that the `previousSibling` element to the clicked button will not be a `td` cell, though. If it is, then your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Could you share some more of your html code for context?
Also, I see that you are referencing this which doesn't exist. You should use btn.previousSubling....

Comment: you need to get your parent td of the button before doing previous: `btn.parentElement.previousSibling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to walk the DOM tree:

1. btn parent
2. div parent
3. table cell previous sibling

```
function addArticle(btn) {
   
    var RowNumber = btn.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
    alert(RowNumber);
}
```